# Redeploying a Flask app in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

How do I redeploy an updated version of the Flask web app in Google App Engine.

For example, I have running web app and now there are new features added into it and needs redeployment. How can I do that?

Also how to remove the previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run the same command you used to originally deploy the app:

```
$ gcloud app deploy
```

This will replace the currently running instances with the new app.

Comment: thanks @dustin, but will it take the modified code or should I follow the complete deployment process again?

Comment: yes, the deployment is atomic. Of course it's boring because you have to redeploy all, but in case of issue, you can quickly rollback to a previous version thanks to traffic splitting feature.

Answer (score 0):

Add `--no-promote` if you want to deploy without routing service to the latest version deployed.